# How do I uninstall the Xbox Game Bar?

Tags: windows, windows-11

The Xbox Game Bar just served me an advertisement and I want to get rid of it. Unfortunately, I no longer see an option to disable it in Settings.

I also can't uninstall it as a program because the "Uninstall" button is greyed out. How do I get rid of this app?

Answer (score 6):

#### Steps to remove Game Bar

1. Open PowerShell as administrator
2. Uninstall the Game Bar:

```
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay | Remove-AppxPackage
```

3. Disable the game recorder software :

```
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameDVR /f /t REG_DWORD /v "AppCaptureEnabled" /d 0
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore /f /t REG_DWORD /v "GameDVR_Enabled" /d 0
```

---

Note the third step works around  around the overlay issue mentioned by @dmiguel  (see [reddit](https://old.reddit.com/r/WindowsHelp/comments/108ngxr/properly_uninstalling_xbox_gamebar_and_resolve/)).

Comment: I think you could do the registry steps in PowerShell as well. Maybe an improvement to the answer? +1.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open PowerShell as an administrator.
2. Type in `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay | Remove-AppxPackage`.

Xbox Game Bar is now gone.

Edit: Heads up that this doesn't work well because from now on your games will bring up a popup that says "You'll need an app to open this ms-gamingoverlay link". It looks like Windows 11 has hooks in the operating system that directly reach out to this package, so it's actually not possible to remove it cleanly.